# Android : how to remove the downloaded android update

Tags: updates, security, system, files, vpn

I have a securities concern. I installed a VPN software on my android and just after (the next day) android asks me do install an update (that is already downloaded via the VPN). I don't fully trust my VPN software and I can not trust that the downloaded update is legitimate. I would like to force Android to redownload this update but from OUTSIDE the VPN (so delete the downloaded file and let android redownload it). How to do that?

Comment: It would help if you mention which Android device and Android version you are using. For some devices, clearing data and cache of system update app is sufficient, while for some pre-8.0 devices, the update might be located in the cache partition. Additionally, OTA updates in non-A/B devices are cryptographically verified by the recovery partition that the update is genuine (comes from the oem) so your fear might be unfounded. I don't know about such verification for a/b devices though.

Comment: @Firelord :  OTA updates in non-A/B devices are cryptographically verified by the recovery partition that the update is genuine (comes from the oem) so your fear might be unfounded ... are you really sure :(

Comment: Check "5." under "Life of an OTA" here: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/nonab